# How may types are there in the Freebase database?

Tags: freebase

I read that for every entity, there can be one or more types associated with it. Overall, what are all the types available/covered in Freebase and is there a place where I can get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [23425](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/type/type%22,%22return%22%3a%22count%22%7D%5D&autorun=true) types in Freebase, but many of them have no or very few entities associated with them.  The most interesting types are those in the "commons" and you can see those, grouped by domain, on the Freebase [home page](http://www.freebase.com/home).

You can get a complete list of the commons types using a query like [this](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/type/type%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22id%22%3anull,%22domain%22%3a%5B%7B%22key%22%3a%5B%7B%22namespace%22%3a%7B%22id%22%3a%22/%22%7D,%22limit%22:0%7D%5D,%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull%7D%5D,%22limit%22:2200%7D%5D).  That will give you all current 2,174 types which belong to domain in the root ("/") along with their name, id, and the domain they belong to.

Comment: 18 months later in April, 2014, it is 25,330 types for the first query and 2,218 for the second which includes only those types in the commons.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
{
  "type": "/type/type",
  "return": "estimate-count"
}
```

You get **40616, as 17 June 2013**